# How would I express an expression in terms of a function?

Tags: equation-solving

To give a simple example, let's say I have

```
f[a_,b_]:=2a+b

expr = 2a-2b
```

You can immediately see that using the definition of f, `expr=f[a,-2b]`. It is precisely these arguments `{a, -2b}` that I need. With built-in functions this already works, for example

```
Simplify[Log[a] + Log[b], a > 0 && b > 0]
```

returns `Log[a b]`.

How would I tell Mathematica to calculate these arguments for me automatically?

Naïvely, I would expect to be able to do something like

```
Solve[temp == expr, f[a, b]]
```

but this doesn't work. I am probably not phrasing the problem in the correct way for Mathematica to understand it.

Comment: but `expr == 2 a - 2 b` gives `True` since you already set `expr` to be `2 a - 2 b` earlier. Could you explain again what is it you are trying to solve for?  You can't solve for `f[a, b]` because `f[a, b]` evaluates to `2*a+b`

Comment: I am trying to solve for the arguments of f, which should be {a, -2b}. Sorry, the second line with `Solve[]` was just an example of what I would like to be able to do. I have edited it to try to be more clear.

Comment: I will not write this as an answer as it would be quite fragile, but for a linear function of `a` and `b`: `{(expr /. b -> 0)/D[f[a, b], a] , (expr /. a -> 0)/D[f[a, b], b] }`

Comment: @Syed, that would be nice, but in general the functions I am working with are not so simple and have many more arguments. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: But there is also `f[-b, 2 a] == expr`, so how do you know that you want `{a, -2b}` rather than `{-b, 2a}`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `Module[]` is what you are looking for:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html

```
f[a_, b_] := Module[{output},
  output = {2 a, -2 b};
  Return[output]]  

f[a, b]
(*{2 a, -2 b}*)

f[foo, bar]
(*{2 foo, -2 bar}*)

f[1, 2]
(*{2, -4}*)
```